# How to scroll div to bottom?

Tags: javascript, html

Now I have div with following properties:

```
.chat-history {
    height: 70%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

How to scroll it to bottom using js?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript scrollTo function

```
 window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
```

Where 0 is the horizontal scoll and the second parameter is the vertical scroll.

For your example you should get the element and use that element instead of window, like this:

```
getElementsByClassName('chat-history')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `scrollTop` function in `Javascript`

### Example:

```
var obj = document.getElementById("Name of your div");
obj.scrollTop = obj.scrollHeight;
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/js1vyrxr/3/

If you want to use it with `jQuery` you can use something like this

```
$("#ScrollToThisDivID").scrollTop($("#ScrollToThisDivID")[0].scrollHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.scrollTo(0, document.getElementsByClassName('chat-history')[0].scrollHeight);
```

I think this will work as you needed. you have to write the class name of the div where you are showing the messages.